# Refreshing / Creating developer sandbox from partial or full sandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, enterprise

In Enterprise edition of Salesforce, I remember being able to create or refresh a developer sandbox from a partial or full sandbox instead of production. This would also copy over some of the data that was in those sandboxes.

I recently went to attempt this and it appear this is no longer a feature.

Looked through release notes for the last year and couldn't find anything about this. Did Salesforce remove this feature? or was this never a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any [such feature ever existing](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JawvAAC) (the ability to spin up or refresh a Sandbox from another one), so I can't speak to that exactly, but you can still [clone a sandbox today under certain circumstances, but only from Production](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also stuck with the same issue whose answer is here:-)

When you clone a sandbox, all its data and metadata are copied to the new sandbox. A cloned sandbox uses the same license type as its source org. For example, to clone a Full sandbox you must have a Full sandbox license available.

Thanks

Darshna